# Oracle Group By Field - Field

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm new to SQL and I have 2 fields, one of which I need to minus from the other and display as Total. I tried putting it in my select statement `AS` Total but it threw an error so I though I'd try `Group By` but that didn't work well either. How do I a column Total as Revenue - Cost in SQL?

```
SELECT PROJECT_NAME, DESCRIPTION, PROJECT_DATE, COST, REVENUE
FROM PROJECT
GROUP BY (REVENUE - COST) AS TOTAL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your request, you can use:

```
SELECT PROJECT_NAME, 
  DESCRIPTION, 
  PROJECT_DATE, 
  REVENUE,
  COST,
  (REVENUE - COST) as Total
FROM PROJECT
```

The `GROUP BY` would be used if you were attempting to aggregate data.  For example if your table had multiple entries for each project and you wanted a total, then you might use:

```
SELECT PROJECT_NAME, 
  DESCRIPTION, 
  PROJECT_DATE, 
  SUM(REVENUE - COST) as Total
FROM PROJECT
GROUP BY PROJECT_NAME, DESCRIPTION, PROJECT_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT PROJECT_NAME, DESCRIPTION, PROJECT_DATE, COST, REVENUE, ( REVENUE - COST ) profit
FROM PROJECT
```